# Proper way to have intellisense using jsdoc or typescript for a sequelize model

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, sequelize.js, jsdoc

I am working on a very old codebase, a legacy project, they are asking me to add more funcionality to it and I want to do it in a clean and documented way.

I am adding sequelize ORM for my task doing a loop to properly add relationship between my entities (code below) and I want to be able to have intellisense/typehinting for my entities.

This is a very old project so not typescript is configured and neither I could add it the traditional way, they use pug and some HTML imports for the javascript files so I couldn't directly add a tsconfig.ts and add ts-node, I can't pass the entire code through the typescript compiler so that's why I think using JSDoc directly is good

`(In case you know a way to use typescript with this consideration, only for getting better DX by having typehining and intellisense please let me know, I highly prefer typescript over JSDoc but I don't know how could I set it up with this consideration)`

Example entity:

```js
/** Usuario model */
module.exports = (sequelize) => {
  class Usuario extends Model {}
  // Usuario.findAll this show intellisense properly
  module.exports = { Usuario, };
  Usuario.init(...);

  Usuario.associations = (models) => {
    Usuario.belongsToMany(models.Pueblo, {
      through: "table",
      foreignKey: "fk",
      otherKey: "fk2",
    });
  };

  return Usuario;
};
```

DBConnection.js

Since I am doign this automatic processs of importing all entities and linking them in runtime, the types are not being recognized by the IDE.

```js
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.APP_PG_CONEXION);
const db = require("./sequelize-types");

fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, "models"))
  .filter((file) => {
    return file.indexOf(".") !== 0 && file.slice(-3) === ".js";
  })
  .forEach((file) => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, "models", file))(
      sequelize,
      DataTypes
    );
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach((modelName) => {
  if (db[modelName].associations) {
    db[modelName].associations(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = { database: db };
```

I added a sequelize_types.js file with some JSDoc types, like trying to "hack" the typehinting to make it work by force:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {import("./models/Usuario").Usuario} Usuario
 *
 */

/**
 * @typedef {Object} DbInstance
 * @property {Usuario} Usuario
 *
 */

/** @type {DbInstance} */
const db = {};

module.exports = db;
```

then I use this type-injected db object into the DBConnection to be populated with the linked entities.

All good, the code works but the intellisense does not, if I, in another try something like this:

```js
await database.Usuario.
```

#### I do get some type hinting but it's like it's not the full set of types.

[image]

#### For example, the findAll method is not being recognized:

[image]

#### Just for testing sake, if I try the same typehinting test in the very Usuario entity file, it does work:

[image]

#### There it also has some of the methods shown in the other file like the addHook at the top:

[image]

---

So it's like if something is missing and I can't point out what.

I insist, if there is a better way to do it through typescript instead, I beg you tell me please, only consider that I can't use the typescript compiler so, somehow the setup should be for development only and for typehinting/intellisense sake

Thank you.